# Delete Checkbox in the same row does not update the row color

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I can get the `checkbox` when placed outside the table to work, but **how can I get it to work `toggle/inside` the row with `fontawesome-trash` can.**? with  a `strike line or red color` through the row to indicate delete/undeleted.

Here is the [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/9hz931ek/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This** Please run the Code Snippet

You need to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

**.closest() :-** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. Begins with the current element. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector

```js
$('.clsChk').click(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
   $(this).closest('tr.rowClass').css({'color':'red'});
  }
  else{
  $(this).closest('tr.rowClass').css({'color':'black'});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="checkboxID"> Del / Undelete </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" />

<table id="tableID">
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>** 1) First child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
            <td>** 2) Second child cell of '.rowClass' </td>
            <td>** 3) this checkbox needs a delete 
                <input class='clsChk'  type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" />
            </td> <!--how to make this work-->
        </tr>
        
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>No class for this row</td>
            <td>(Still no class)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>** 1) First child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
            <td>** 2) Second child cell of '.rowClass' </td>
            <td>** 3) this checkbox needs a delete 
                <input class='clsChk'  type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" />
            </td> <!--how to make this work-->
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>** 1) First child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
            <td>** 2) Second child cell of '.rowClass' </td>
            <td>** 3) this checkbox needs a delete 
                <input class='clsChk'  type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" />
            </td> <!--how to make this work-->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: hi this is great, I want to know, what if there are other controls like dropdownlists etc... will those controls also ..also change color.  I only want to change the color of the text, and on toggle/Undelete - take it back to previous state

Comment: @transformer  This will only change text color. It will not change any HTML control color.
If this answer helps you then please up vote and tick as answer ... So it will helps other to find out correct answer.

Comment: one more thing please, not working for me, i have  `<td>` and then  `<input class="textBox">` and when I try `tr.td.textBox` as selector - it does not select/find

Comment: My *updated* html code snippet is `<tbody> 
        <tr class="rowClass">
        <td>** 1) .rowClass'  *** Added this <input class="textBox"/> </td>`

Comment: You can use $(this).closest('tr.rowClass').find('.textBox') to get that object

Answer (score 1):

Use `parents` and `is(":checked")` for checked or not.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass("red");
    } else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("red");
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
   
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="rowClass">
            <td>** 1) First child cell of '.rowClass'</td>
            <td>** 2) Second child cell of '.rowClass' </td>
            <td>** 3) this checkbox needs a delete <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxID" /></td> <!--how to make this work-->
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>No class for this row</td>
            <td>(Still no class)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, in m html snippet... I have another input text box inside <td>, with `class=textBox` --- my *updated* html code snippet is `<tbody> 
        <tr class="rowClass">
        <td>** 1) .rowClass'  *** Added this <input class="textBox"/> </td>` FYI - since *I have other controls like dropdowns as well*... inside the tablerow

Comment: is there other js stuff you do on your blog